# Magento wiki moved

Tags: discussion, suggestion

It seems the wiki.magento.com has moved to devdocs.magento.com

Means all link on our stackexchange are invalid now.

$someome should probably start to fix this

Comment: They should define some kind of URL rewrite over there at  Magento

Answer (score 1):

There are only ten posts on the whole site that contain the string `wiki.magento.com`, including links and plaintext, so this shouldn't be a problem to do by hand.

However, when I checked those pages out a minute ago, most of the links that pointed at the `wiki` version of the URL worked just fine for me. For the ones that didn't work, changing the URL to say `devdocs` instead didn't solve the problem. I'm not sure what I'm missing here... can you provide some examples where the current link is broken and also what the new, correct URL is?